Can I run W10 on a Linux server (No Desktop) with VMM or do I need a Desktop installed on that server?
This is probably a stupid question ?
I am wondering if I can run W10 on my Ubuntu server with VMM or do I need a Ubuntu Desktop ?
Thanks

Interesting suggestion...I will need to investigate this solution to understand how to implement this as I do have my server running on the same network as my desktop.

Both are on the same subnet and the server is managed via ssh. I am the admin on both as well. The network is 1Gb... I hope not too much lag and latency on the VMM side running a regular W10 Desktop.

Tada...done.
Running QEMU/KVM on the server and VMM on an Ubuntu desktop does work and is trivial to set up using VMM ssh+qemu to create a connection between the desktop and the server.
Thanks for the tips.
